# How to set timeout Geocoder android?

Tags: android, timeout, google-geocoder

I've use `Geocoder` to searching locations from name, here is my code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(text, 10);
```

`text` below get from `searchView`.

It work fine, but when wifi not connect (lost internet), this `searchView` be hang until it get response from server: `Timed out waiting for response from server`.
This take my UI look like hang and crash anytime. Can I change timeout of `Geocoder`, about 3s or less?

Any helps. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `Geocoder` in `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: No, this code is all I have.

Comment: Well, then put your `Geocoder` inside `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` method and handle the result in `onPostExecute` method. It will prevent your App from hanging and crashing.

Here is the official documentation of using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)